# how to explicitly close file descriptor in a loop in rust?

Tags: file, rust

I know I can call `drop` to close fd explicitly. But what if the file is used inside a loop?

Can I deal with it without using the unsafe code blocks?

Suppose this scenario:
I want to write into a file every 10 seconds, and this file will be changed every 10 minutes. File name is generated by timestamp.

```rust
let mut file = File::create("ts1").unwrap();
loop {
    file.write(buf).unwrap();
    
    if time_elapsed() > 10 * 60 {
        // how to close the old fd?
        // drop cannot be used because it is inside the loop
        file = File::create("ts2").unwrap();
    }
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
}
```

Comment: When you assign to a variable, the old value is dropped. For a file this means it is closed.

Comment: You say "drop cannot be used because it is inside the loop" but the compiler does not complain.  What's your reasoning here?  It gets dropped implicitly when it goes out of scope anyways.

Comment: "I am new to rust and I don't know [insert thing]". You should read the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch00-00-introduction.html) it covers all these basic things

Comment: @vallentin Actually, I believe this is not covered by the book (although one may argue it is implied by common sense, otherwise we would have memory leaks).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The book does talk about ["Cleanup with the Drop Trait"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-03-drop.html), it even mentions files as an example

Comment: @vallentin But it doesn't mention that assignment drops, if my memory is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I can call drop to close fd explicitly. But what if the file is used inside a loop?

It doesn't matter? As long as the compiler can see that you've re-set the local variable to a valid value between dropping it and the next use it's happy. Here it's not even useful, re-assigning will necessarily drop the old value beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a way to sync operation done on file object to disk. In that case, you don't need to drop object but call `sync_all`.

```
let mut file = File::create("ts1").unwrap();
loop {
    file.write(buf).unwrap();
    
    if time_elapsed() > 10 * 60 {
        // how to close the old fd?
        // drop cannot be used because it is inside the loop
        let _ = file.sync_all();
        file = File::create("ts2").unwrap();
    }
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
}
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `sync_all` since the file is closed immediately afterwards anyway?

Comment: One advantage is that you can get notified of sync errors, which sadly is not the case for drop. Not that that notification is overly helpful as we (re)discovered a few years back during fsyncgate, but you can at least know you're hosed, which you simply can not know using drop.

Comment: This answer, as well as the comments, seem to confuse syncing with flushing. `fsync_all()` unnecessarily waits for data to be written to permanent storage, which is not what closing a file descriptor normally does (nor should it). In many scenarios it is useful to explicitly **flush** the file, for reasons outlined by @Masklinn, but here even that is a no-op since `file` is unbuffered.

Comment: Although it is by no means free, syncing before closing is as useful if not more so than flushing before closing, as it provides significantly stronger persistence / reliability guarantees.

Comment: Flushing before closing is useless since it happens automatically when the file is dropped anyway. Syncing before closing is unusual because if you really need to sync, then you should probably have done it immediately after writing the critical data, instead of waiting until the file is about to be closed.